# Separate Audio and Video in android

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am beginner to Android application development,The aim of my project is to separate a audio and video from video file. after surfing in internet i came to know that, using FFmpeg we can do it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv # show stream numbers and formats
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy audio.m4a # AAC
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy audio.mp3 # MP3
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy audio.ac3 # AC3
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -an -c copy video.mkv
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:1 -c copy audio.m4a # stream 1
```

separated video file wouldn't contain any audio it must be  contain only video type.
whether this option too possible in ffmpeg?
is any other alternative option there?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Copy only video

Yes, it is possible to [scream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) only the video from an input with the [`-map`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -codec copy output.mkv
```

- This will stream copy all video streams from the first input (the only input in this case) to the output.
- If the input has more than one video stream and you only want the first video stream then use `-map 0:v:0`.
- The `-an` option can also be used instead, but this only excludes audio resulting in the potential to copy other stream types including subtitles, data, and attachments.
- See [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) for more info on how ffmpeg will choose streams for inclusion in the output.

## Copy only audio

This is very similar to the above example: just change the `-map` option to use a different [stream specifier](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -map 0:a -codec copy output.mp3
```

Comment: Is there any better android api's other than ffmpeg to accomplish the above. Because ffmpeg have lot of build procedures, so i would prefer if there is some default Api's in Android itself.

Comment: @Manoj, just look at the processing you have to do to accomplish your task. So `No` there is no api in android to achieve this. You have to use `Ffmpeg` or any such similar external library.