# How to convert recorded or existing video in audio file?

Tags: android, audio, video-conversion

Application will open/record video from gallery/camera, after that application should automatically convert that video to audio file. I have searched a lot on google but i unable to get any solution for  this. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: it can be done using ffmpeg, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21762561/3117966)

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041079/how-to-extract-audio-from-video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is one library that can do the trick which is called FFmpeg. you
>   can found it here http://ffmpeg.org/ .

The best way is you can use bambuster (http://bambuser.com/opensource) which is open source and provides you code for your `FFmpeg` android app. so, you can easily convert your video file.

Answer (score 0):

> FFMPEG is the best option for Audio capturing from Video.

Answer (score 0):

Even i was stuck on this same year back. wanted to make app like Dubmash. but didn't find solution anywhere on stackoverflow. but luckily i found one project which did these type of functionality i extracted the part i wanted i.e getting audio from a video file.

here check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117316/3479012). i answered it to one question last year. please have a look.

well i dont know how good/bad it is in performance o anything. but main thing is it worked for me